# Can we discribe a Lie group action from some local property?

Tags: lie-groups, group-actions

Let **G** be a Lie group,and it acts on a smooth manifold **M**.Then can we get that the action is transitive from some local property of the Lie group action.More precisely,Can we get the action is transitive by research the action on a neighbourhood of some point in **M** or a neighbourhood of some element in **G**.Is there some similar result?.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just knowing about the action in a neighborhood of one point of the manifold tells you nothing about whether the action is transitive. For example, consider the standard action of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ on $\mathbb R^n$. This action is not transitive, because it fixes the origin. On the other hand, we can restrict the action to $\mathbb R^n\smallsetminus\{0\}$, and then it becomes transitive. But these actions are indistinguishable if we look only in a small neighborhood of a particular point of $\mathbb R^n\smallsetminus\{0\}$.

On the other hand, if you know something local about the action in a neighborhood of *every* point, then sometimes something can be said. For example, given a smooth action of a Lie group $G$ on a smooth manifold $M$, for each point $p\in M$ we get a linear map $\phi_p\colon \operatorname{Lie}(G)\to T_pM$ by 
$$
\phi_p(\xi) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} (\exp t\xi)\cdot p.
$$

**Theorem.** If $M$ is connected and $\phi_p$ is surjective for each $p\in M$,
then the action of $G$ is transitive.

The proof basically boils down to showing that each orbit is open. (This is problem 20-13 in my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, 2nd ed.)